# an array is automatically stringified in rails with mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, mongodb, mongoid

I'm new in using rails with mongoid and i have problems in storing an array in some field

Here is the code to clarify everything

in my model :

```
class Something
    include Mongoid::Document
    field :some_field, type: Array
end
```

in my controller :

```
def create
@something = Something.new(something_params)
    @something[:some_field] = params[:something][:some_field].split(',')
    if @something.save
        redirect_to @something, notice: "whatever"
    else
        render "new"
    end
end
```

in my view :

```
<%= form_for @something do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :some_field %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :some_field %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

when i use it that way i get an error message :
"Problem: Value of type String cannot be written to a field of type Array Summary: Tried to set a value of type String to a field of type Array Resolution: Verify if the value to be set correspond to field definition"

but when i change the field type to String , it is successfully added but with a stringified array

I tried this :

```
render :text => @something[:some_field] #outputs : ["field1", "field2", "field3"]
```

but

```
render :text => @something[:some_field].inspect  #outputs : "[\"field1\", \"field2\", \"field3\"]"
```

What should i do to store the value as an Array ?

Thanks

Comment: Is it the `Something.new(something_params)` that is complaining? Presumably `:some_field` is a string in `something_params`, right?

Comment: yes , you are right ! .. but when can i split the `:some_field` so that it can be stored as an array ?

Comment: I think you have to use update_attributes

Comment: What format are you expecting people to type into the `<textarea>`? Some sort of CSV?

Comment: a normal text separated by commas .. that's why i'm trying to split it with `split` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out what's wrong

I have to modify the hash value to be an array before calling

```
@something = Something.new(something_params)
```

so , i had to type this first :

```
@something[:some_field] = params[:something][:some_field].split(',')
```

The code that works is :

```
def create
    @something[:some_field] = params[:something][:some_field].split(',')
    @something = Something.new(something_params)
    if @something.save
        redirect_to @something, notice: "whatever"
    else
        render "new"
    end
end
```

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Add .reject(&:blank?) after you split(","). I also use mongoid but with multi select. I changed my code to text_area and this code worked for me. Also an example http://funonrails.com/2012/01/mongoid-array-field-and-rails-form/

```
@something[:some_field]=params[:something][:some_field].split(',').reject(&:blank?)
```

Comment: @archie it is not assigned as an array anyway .. it is converted to a stringified array .. so , it is not about saving .. it is before saving ( i think )

Comment: You need to add reject(&:blank?) after you split array